# Share session between HTTPURLConnection with webview in Android

Tags: java, android, jsp, session, android-webview

I am developing an app which send request to server for login authentication when login is success then I set the username in session & my session is created. I show the jsp pages of server on the webview so my jsp page require the session but they don't found any session because it was created by the HTTPURLConnection. So I want to know how can I share the session of HTTPURLConnection to webview.

Code for setting session

```
String uname=request.getparameter("Username");
if(LoginSucesss)
{
    session.setAttribute("uid",uname);
}
```

Please don't mark this question as duplicate it is orignal.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can sync cookies though.

Comment: I don't want to use cookies. is there any way out ?

Comment: to the best of my knowledge, I don't think so

Comment: Ok. how do i do it using cookies ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Get cookie manager for WebView
    // This must occur before setContentView() instantiates your WebView
    android.webkit.CookieSyncManager webCookieSync =
        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
    android.webkit.CookieManager webCookieManager =
        CookieManager.getInstance();
    webCookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);

    // Get cookie manager for HttpURLConnection
    java.net.CookieStore rawCookieStore = ((java.net.CookieManager)
        CookieHandler.getDefault()).getCookieStore();

    // Construct URI
    java.net.URI baseUri = null;
    try {
        baseUri = new URI("http://www.example.com");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // Handle invalid URI
        ...
    }

    // Copy cookies from HttpURLConnection to WebView
    List<HttpCookie> cookies = rawCookieStore.get(baseUri);
    String url = baseUri.toString();
    for (HttpCookie cookie : cookies) {
        String setCookie = new StringBuilder(cookie.toString())
            .append("; domain=").append(cookie.getDomain())
            .append("; path=").append(cookie.getPath())
            .toString();
        webCookieManager.setCookie(url, setCookie);
    }

   //TODO:Your Code
}
```

Comment: is it compulsary to write down the code in onCreate(). I have HTTPURLConnection & webview in diffrent clasees?

Comment: The basic point here is to show how it gets done, now its upon you how you should be implementing it, but remember to do all this things before using setContentView(R.layout.someLayout);

Comment: I am getting the cookie which i set through the servlet using the following method in android 
connection.getHeaderField()
But how do i pass this to webview?

Comment: if(ucon.getResponseCode()==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
    {
      String h=ucon.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");
      Log.i("RAE","Cookie is="+ h);
      Map<String, List<String>> headerFields = ucon.getHeaderFields();
      List<String> cookiesHeader = headerFields.get("Set-Cookie");
      for(int i=0;i<cookiesHeader.size();i++)
      {
       Log.i("R", cookiesHeader.get(i));
      }
    }

Comment: if your webview is in another activity and you want to share some some data (cookies) between activities, you can use setArguments(), or you can use Android shared prefrences to store data for some time and then purge it, or your can create a single instance class to use data across multiple activities and classes

Comment: How to send cookie with webview.do you hvae some sample code

Comment: If you're passing cookies around to activities you can try using intent.setextra () or parcellable for the connection object (?)